# Paypal Classic API: How to get proper credentials

Tags: paypal

I've tried to follow [Paypal's API instructions to create my API credentials](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/#creating-classic-api-credentials) with no luck.

In my Paypal account I have no "Tools" menu. I've also tried "Profile -> My Selling Tools -> API Access" as stated [sdk's wiki](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java/wiki/SDK-Configuration-Parameters) but the latter menu option doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance for your support

Answer (score 0):

As written in the same "Paypal's API instructions to create my API credentials" document: You must have a PayPal Business account to make calls to the live PayPal servers.

I suggest you to contact PayPal or maybe this link will help you [Sign up for a business account - PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/merchantsignup/router/us/wps)!